# Is there a relation between origin of Hinduism and Veda?

Tags: vedas

Is there a relation between origin of Hinduism and Veda? "Veda" is considered as the oldest religious book and Hinduism is the oldest religion. Did they both originate simultaneously?

Comment: Vedas were not written in 500 BC. That's the date given by the Indologists to support their Aryan Invasion Theory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lets leave Ramayan... people are confused about 24th Treta and recent Treta in this matter...

Even if we go in the Mahabharat... Planetary configuration calculation gives the date 5 thousand years ago ... And by common sense Ramayan happened before that.. This date is sufficient to make it oldest religion in the world... In Valmiki Ramayan every 1st letter of 1000th verse forms Gayatri mantra which is of Rig Veda.. Which means there was Rig Veda at that time also...

People also talk about presence of Saraswati river in Rig Veda, other other like finding of archaeological sites, finding Dwarka, genetics, tribes story, etc..

But for me astronomical dating of whole Mahabharat book is sufficient to make it oldest religion in the world as such huge astronomical combination can not be merely imagined and written....